# How do I fix a real-time-clock made in Javascript(I can't see it in the webpage)?

Tags: javascript, real-time-clock

I was trying to create a clock following some tutorials on the internet but I'm having a problem. The clock should update itself every second and should show the current time. May I have your help please? This should be the result:https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock . This is my code:

```js
function startClock() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  console.log(currentTime);

  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
  console.log(currentHours);

  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  console.log(currentMinutes);

  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
  console.log(currentSeconds);

  currentMinutes = checkTime(m);

  currentSeconds = checkTime(s);

  var time = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;

  var repeatTime = setTimeout(startClock, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
    return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `startClock();` to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four problems in your code:

1. The `startClock()` function will call `setTimeout()` to make sure it gets called again. But it never gets called initially. Thus, add the statement `startClock();` at the end, near the `</script>`.
2. The variable `m` does not exist. Fix this by writing `currentMinutes = checkTime(currentMinutes);`.
3. The variable `s` does not exist. Fix this by writing `currentSeconds = checkTime(currentSeconds);`.
4. The `checkTime()` function returns nothing (`undefined`) if `i` is not less than 10. Hence, add the statement `else return "" + i;`.

Fix all of them and it runs! I did test the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Check the gist [CurrentTimeData.js](https://gist.github.com/elsheikh21/42b535c6f097bc9a28104dd65053a298)